# FS100 controller ROS integration with firmware version FS3.27.00-00

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I want to integrate our FS100 Controller with ROS. In a recent wiki update it has been said that the controller software version FS3.30.00-00 doesn't require purchasing the software option to enable MotoPlus Option Function, nevertheless our controller has active (and in use) the MotoPlus Option Function; this might be related with the fact that we had purchased in the past the Motofit, Motosight and MotoCOM licences.

I don't know if I am confused or not, but with this MotoPlus "Option Function" enabled in the controller, is it required still to upgrade or order the software tool from Yaskawa, or are there more requirements that aren't meet by the FS3.27.00-00 version?.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275392/fs100-controller-ros-integration-with-firmware-version-fs3.27.00-00/) by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

There are additional internal settings beyond just the MotoPlus Option Function.  But given the use of MotoSight on your controller, it is very likely that these are already configured.  There are two settings which I am unsure about since there are multiple editions of the MotoSight product.

So, I would encourage you to try loading the MotoROS.out file according to the tutorial on the wiki.  (Skip the MOTOMAN DRIVER sentence.)  If there are any internal settings configured improperly, then you will get an alarm 8003 [xxx] at startup.  If the xxx is a value of 100 - 111, then you must contact your local Yaskawa Motoman office and request the FS3.30.00-00 upgrade.  If it is a value of 1 - 8, then you can easily resolve these settings yourself by following the steps listed here. http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Troubleshooting

Please note that we are currently debugging another possible issue with the latest version of FS100 software and MotoROS.  If you get an alarm that says, "Cannot save parameter file", then please reply to this message thread and I will notify you as soon as we have a resolution for this issue.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

---

Ted Miller - Yaskawa Motoman (US)

---

Originally posted by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) with karma: 101 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2017-11-09**:
Thanks Ted, I want to ask you another thing, if we load the MotoROS.out file in the controller, will this mean that we have to uninstall any other features from the controller (Motofit/sight/COM) or only disable them; Other colleagues need to work with this old features, off course they wont use ROS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-09**:
@danfoa: could I ask you to open a new question for this? I know it is related, but ROS Answers is a single-question-single-answer site. Visibility of questions is much higher than comments, so if this stays a comment other users with the same question may not be able to find it.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2017-11-09**:
Ok :), this is the new question #q275452, if anyone is interested.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-09**:
Thanks.

Tip: to refer to other questions, you can use the `#qNNNNNN` format. It will auto-link.

**Comment by [Danfoa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32545/danfoa/) on 2018-02-23**:
Hallo Ted, I just wanted to say that finally got the approval to install MotoROS but I did got Alarm 105 when reseting the controller, I already contacted Yaskawa for the software upload procedure, but wanted to post here what happened.